# Buttons not showing above Capacitor Camera Preview in Android

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am building an app which uses camera preview to capture image. But when i use it in android device. It hides the button and show only preview. I am not able to click picture as there is no button shown.

**Library Used:** capacitor-community/camera-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in your css, that the z-index of your overlay is set into a constant and is of less value than the z-index of your buttons.

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.cameraPreview {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```